# Exception inside if condition in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a cursor for inserting employee data from temp table to main table. I have a scenario in which first it will check if temp table department id is exist in main department table; if `DeptId` does not exist then don't insert employee and update ERR_MSG column in temp table.  I am handling exception inside if condition after INSERT statement, but it is giving me an error like

> Encountered symbol EXCEPTION when expecting one of the following : begin,end,case,else......

sample code is as below:-

```
DECLARE
 --var list

    BEGIN
     OPEN ltempCur For

         -- here i am selecting cols from temp table in variables

     LOOP
        FETCH ltempCur 
     INTO 
       --all the declared variables here
     EXIT
    WHEN ltempCur %NOTFOUND;
    BEGIN

     --select statement for checking if employee record exist in table

     IF(lExist == 0)  --if emloyee record not exist
     THEN

       begin
         --check if dept exist in dept table if not exist then i have assigned zero to deptid variable in NO_DATA_FOUND exception
       end;

       IF(vardeptid > 0)  --if condition for which i have mentioned in description

       --Insert statement for employee

       EXCEPTION
       WHEN OTHERS
       THEN
           --handling exp
       COMMIT;
    END;         

       END IF; -- dept id check if end

     --end loop -- close cursor
```

In above code, if I remove `deptid` IF  ELSE condition then it is working fine, but with that IF condition it is giving error

Comment: You shouldn't put an  `EXCEPTION` section within `IF.. END IF` .Use `RAISE` statement if you want to raise an user defined exception when a condition is satisfied. `EXCEPTION` section  should be at the  end of a `BEGIN..END`  and can handle or re-raise required exceptions.

Comment: i want to check if employee insert happens successfully or not, that is why i wrote EXCEPTION after insert statement of employee, can i check rowcount after insert and raise exception if it is zero after END IF?

Comment: If you want a specific EXCEPTION handler for inserting Employee record then you need to frame that insert statement in a proper block: `BEGIN insert ... EXECPTION ... END;`

Answer (score 0):

There is a single end if against two IF clauses. Probably, you have not ended the IF clause  for variable lExists.

Comment: I have ended it, jst did not mention in above sample code.

Comment: Okay.  All the IF clauses must end within the same begin end block in which they were started

Comment: yes, i am doing that, and if i comment out IF and END IF of dept exist then code works fine, i think i have to raise exception in dept exist if and then handle it at the end, have to google some stuff :-D

Comment: Not really, I believe. You could put an exception handler before end in the begin section where you are checking if dept exist in dept table.

Comment: *I have ended it, just did not mention in above sample code* - then what code are we trying to fix here?